# Validate BizTalk Schema in Visual Studio - "Custom component invocation failed"

Tags: xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Well, that error message doesn't help at all.  I have a flat file schema that I cannot get working.

The XML is valid, but BizTalk can't work with it.  Is there a way to enable verbose error logging when calling Validate Schema?  Is there a better tool for validating/testing BizTalk schemas than Visual Studio?

I'm new to BizTalk and I'm stumped.

Comment: What's BizTalk version? What do you mean by "BizTalk can't work with it"?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is wrong in your call to validate the schema. By any chance, did you forget to set the Input Instance Filename property?

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems: Schemas built using the flat file wizard inexplicably default to Xml source.  So it didn't know it wasn't dealing with .txt.  Plus I had it set to expect 0 records.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had faced the same problem.

I had build a tool to convert TDS1 format schema to flat file schema. The xml schema was correct but it was not getting validated. Then i compared with my existing flat file schema and i found that child delimiter type was wrong. My tool was creating flat file schema with delimiter type set to hex for all the record info.
But ; is a character and not hex.

original record info attribute:  child_delimiter_type="**hex**"

Changed record info attribute:  child_delimiter_type="**char**"

So please check your delimiter type and other record info attributes as well.

Hope this will help....